# Draw ShapeType.Line objects in all directions with GemBox.Document

Tags: c#, gembox-document

High Level Business Need:

1.) Grab input from user in order to create object data for constructing lines, rectangles, `text` and `fields`.

2.) Using `input` from user create doc templates via `GemBox.Document` (currently stuck here for lines)
3.) Ingest work object merge data to doc `template`(s) to populate fields, save as image.

I believe i should be able to figure out #2 for rectangles and text as the way the objects are constructed are similar to how Shape works for `GemBox.Document`. However, the object for Line is not the same, providing `point1` and length/width, not `point1` and `point2`.

I'm categorizing 3 types of lines...

1.) Flat
2.) Positive Pitch
3.) Negative Pitch

... I've been able to figure out flat (no horizontal or vertical delta) and positive pitch (line from top left to bottom right or its mirror bottom right to top left) but have been unable to figure out a negative pitch (line from top right to bottom left or its mirror bottom left to top right).

The Shape object will not allow a negative length or negative with attribute to have it draw the way i want. I couldn't see / figure out if there was a way to mutate the line object via a rotation/flip etc.

I'm open to different approaches but i have been told that i do have to use `GemBox.Document`

```
namespace GemBoxDocument_LineDemo
{
    using System;
    using MyModels;
    using GemBox.Document;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using GemBox.Document.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

    public class Program
    {
        //inputs come from a GUI window, we're working with stub/coupon/partial-page/rectangle where w > h
        private const float GUIWIDTH = 425;
        private const float GUIHEIGHT = 200;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

            var gemDoc = new DocumentModel();

            var firstSection = new Section(gemDoc);
            gemDoc.Sections.Add(firstSection);

            var firstParagraph = new Paragraph(gemDoc);
            firstSection.Blocks.Add(firstParagraph);

            var workableWidth = firstSection.PageSetup.PageWidth - (firstSection.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + firstSection.PageSetup.PageMargins.Right);
            //i think this needs to be -something, or * % of total page since we're partial page
            var workableHeight = firstSection.PageSetup.PageHeight - (firstSection.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + firstSection.PageSetup.PageMargins.Bottom);

            var widthMultiplier = workableWidth / GUIWIDTH;
            //for now this has been working just fine...
            var heightMultiplier = widthMultiplier;

            //offset of 0 is whole available workable width from GUI, simulating the offset at 50 for instance will show dynamic input shrinks towards center as this increases
            //don't change it too high as it'd create dynamic negative input which isn't possible fron an input perspective. (negative width and/or height)
            var offset = 0;

            var flatOnHorizontalTOPLine = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = 0 + offset,
                Y = 0 + offset,
                X2 = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y2 = 0 + offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            var flatOnHorizontalBOTTOMLine = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = 0 + offset,
                Y = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                X2 = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y2 = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            var flatOnVerticalLEFTLine = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = 0 + offset,
                Y = 0 + offset,
                X2 = 0 + offset,
                Y2 = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            var flatOnVerticalRIGHTLine = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y = 0 + offset,
                X2 = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y2 = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            var positivePitchPoint1LessThanPoint2 = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = 0 + offset,
                Y = 0 + offset,
                X2 = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y2 = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            var positivePitchPoint1GreaterThanPoint2 = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = 0 + offset,
                Y = 0 + offset,
                X2 = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y2 = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            //else if (templateItem.X < templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y > templateItem.Y2)//negative pitch, point 1 below/ToLeft point 2
            var negativePitchPoint1BelowAndToLeftOfPoint2 = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = 0 + offset,
                Y = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                X2 = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y2 = 0 + offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            //else if (templateItem.X > templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y < templateItem.Y2)//negative pitch, point 1 above/ToRight point 2
            var negativePitchPoint1AboveAndToRightOfPoint2 = new TemplateItem()
            {
                X = GUIWIDTH - offset,
                Y = 0 + offset,
                X2 = 0 + offset,
                Y2 = GUIHEIGHT - offset,
                Pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 1),
                TemplateItemType = TemplateItemType.Line
            };

            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, flatOnHorizontalTOPLine, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, flatOnHorizontalBOTTOMLine, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, flatOnVerticalLEFTLine, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, flatOnVerticalRIGHTLine, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, positivePitchPoint1LessThanPoint2, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, positivePitchPoint1GreaterThanPoint2, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));

            //cannot figure out these two 'negative pitch' instances...
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, negativePitchPoint1BelowAndToLeftOfPoint2, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));
            firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(GetGemboxLineShape(gemDoc, firstSection, negativePitchPoint1AboveAndToRightOfPoint2, heightMultiplier, widthMultiplier));

            gemDoc.Save(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss")}.docx"));

            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static Shape GetGemboxLineShape(DocumentModel document, Section section, TemplateItem templateItem, double heightMultiplier, double widthMultiplier)
        {
            var verticalTranslation = Math.Abs(templateItem.Y2 - templateItem.Y) * heightMultiplier;
            var horizontalTranslation = Math.Abs(templateItem.X2 - templateItem.X) * widthMultiplier;
            var horizontalAbsolutePosition = 0.0;
            var verticalAbsolutePosition = 0.0;

            if ((templateItem.X < templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y < templateItem.Y2) ||//positive pitch, point1 < point2
                (templateItem.X == templateItem.X2) || (templateItem.Y == templateItem.Y2))//flat on the horizontal or vertical
            {
                horizontalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.X * widthMultiplier;
                verticalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.Y * heightMultiplier;

                var gemboxLineShape = new Shape(document, ShapeType.Line, GemBox.Document.Layout.Floating(new HorizontalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + horizontalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.LeftMargin),
                                                                                                          new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + verticalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin),
                                                                                                          new GemBox.Document.Size(horizontalTranslation, verticalTranslation, LengthUnit.Point)));

                gemboxLineShape.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(new GemBox.Document.Color(templateItem.Pen.Color.R, templateItem.Pen.Color.G, templateItem.Pen.Color.B));
                gemboxLineShape.Outline.Width = templateItem.Pen.Width;

                return gemboxLineShape;
            }
            else if (templateItem.X > templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y > templateItem.Y2)//positive pitch, point1 > point2
            {
                //quickly found out i cannot give a negative width or height to GemBox.Document.Size
                //to account for the mirror of the above condition, AKA drawing the same object but in mirror
                //we just flip-flop the starting point / absolute position and create the shape the same way
                horizontalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.X2 * widthMultiplier;
                verticalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.Y2 * heightMultiplier;

                var gemboxLineShape = new Shape(document, ShapeType.Line, GemBox.Document.Layout.Floating(new HorizontalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + horizontalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.LeftMargin),
                                                                                                          new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + verticalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin),
                                                                                                          new GemBox.Document.Size(horizontalTranslation, verticalTranslation, LengthUnit.Point)));

                gemboxLineShape.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(new GemBox.Document.Color(templateItem.Pen.Color.R, templateItem.Pen.Color.G, templateItem.Pen.Color.B));
                gemboxLineShape.Outline.Width = templateItem.Pen.Width;

                return gemboxLineShape;
            }
            else if (templateItem.X < templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y > templateItem.Y2)//negative pitch, point 1 below/ToLeft point 2
            {
                horizontalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.X * widthMultiplier;
                verticalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.Y * heightMultiplier;

                //cannot set negative height for size for it to draw up
                var badLineShape = new Shape(document, ShapeType.Line, GemBox.Document.Layout.Floating(new HorizontalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + horizontalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.LeftMargin),
                                                                                                       new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + verticalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin),
                                                                                                       new GemBox.Document.Size(horizontalTranslation, verticalTranslation, LengthUnit.Point)));

                badLineShape.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(new GemBox.Document.Color(templateItem.Pen.Color.R, templateItem.Pen.Color.G, templateItem.Pen.Color.B));
                badLineShape.Outline.Width = templateItem.Pen.Width;

                return badLineShape;
            }
            else if (templateItem.X > templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y < templateItem.Y2)//negative pitch, point 1 above/ToRight point 2
            {
                horizontalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.X * widthMultiplier;
                verticalAbsolutePosition = templateItem.Y * heightMultiplier;

                //cannot set negative width for size for it to draw left
                var badLineShape = new Shape(document, ShapeType.Line, GemBox.Document.Layout.Floating(new HorizontalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + horizontalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.LeftMargin),
                                                                                                       new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + verticalAbsolutePosition, LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin),
                                                                                                       new GemBox.Document.Size(horizontalTranslation, verticalTranslation, LengthUnit.Point)));

                badLineShape.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(new GemBox.Document.Color(templateItem.Pen.Color.R, templateItem.Pen.Color.G, templateItem.Pen.Color.B));
                badLineShape.Outline.Width = templateItem.Pen.Width;

                return badLineShape;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}

namespace MyModels
{
    using System.Drawing;

    public enum TemplateItemType { Default, Box, Line, Text, Field }
    public class TemplateItem
    {
        public TemplateItemType TemplateItemType { get; set; }
        public Font Font { get; set; }
        public Pen Pen { get; set; }
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public float X2 { get; set; }
        public float Y2 { get; set; }
        public float Width { get; set; }
        public float Height { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            switch (this.TemplateItemType)
            {
                case TemplateItemType.Box:
                    return $"<{this.TemplateItemType.ToString("G")}Item> X<{this.X}> Y<{this.Y}> W<{this.Width}> H<{this.Height}>";
                case TemplateItemType.Line:
                    return $"<{this.TemplateItemType.ToString("G")}Item> X1<{this.X}> Y1<{this.Y}> X2<{this.X2}> Y2<{this.Y2}>";
                case TemplateItemType.Text:
                case TemplateItemType.Field:
                    return $"<{this.TemplateItemType.ToString("G")}Item> X<{this.X}> Y<{this.Y}> W<{this.Width}> H<{this.Height}> T<{this.Text}>";
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the current latest bug fix version [from here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/downloads/BugFixes.htm) and try using the following:

```
badLineShape.Layout.Transform.FlipVertical = true;
```

Regarding the `FlipVertical` and `FlipHorizontal` transformations, in this case (line shape) they should be the same.

For example, consider the following image:

[image: Line drawing]

Applying the vertical flip transformation on it with some photoshop application (I've used Gimp) results in:

[image: Line drawing with vertical flip]

Applying the horizontal flip transformation on it with some photoshop application (I've used Gimp) results in:

[image: Line drawing with horizontal flip]

As you may notice, the resulting images are the same.

Regarding the RightMargin, I'll try to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

As Mario Z has mentioned the new big-fix version v1099 does allow the transformation of lines to create what i'm classifying as a negative pitch line... which now allows to draw lines in all directions.

It appears to be a bit buggy as FlipVertical and FlipHorizontal appear to do the same exact transformation when they shouldn't. I also found a minor bug with setting the floating point via RightMargin, it doesn't appear to function the same way as Top/Left (i haven't tried playing with Bottom yet).

```
public static Shape GetGemboxLineShape(DocumentModel document, Section section, TemplateItem templateItem, double heightMultiplier, double widthMultiplier)
{
    var size = new GemBox.Document.Size(Math.Abs(templateItem.X2 - templateItem.X) * widthMultiplier, Math.Abs(templateItem.Y2 - templateItem.Y) * heightMultiplier, LengthUnit.Point);
    var horizontal = new HorizontalPosition();
    var vertical = new VerticalPosition();
    var requiresNegativeTransform = false;

    if ((templateItem.X < templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y < templateItem.Y2) ||//positive pitch, point1 < point2
        (templateItem.X == templateItem.X2) || (templateItem.Y == templateItem.Y2))//flat on the horizontal or vertical
    {
        horizontal = new HorizontalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + (templateItem.X * widthMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.LeftMargin);
        vertical = new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + (templateItem.Y * heightMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin);
    }
    else if (templateItem.X > templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y > templateItem.Y2)//positive pitch, point1 > point2
    {
        //quickly found out i cannot give a negative width or height to GemBox.Document.Size
        //to account for the mirror of the above condition, AKA drawing the same object but in mirror
        //we just flip-flop the starting point / absolute position and create the shape the same way
        horizontal = new HorizontalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left + (templateItem.X2 * widthMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.LeftMargin);
        vertical = new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + (templateItem.Y2 * heightMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin);
    }
    else if (templateItem.X < templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y > templateItem.Y2)//negative pitch, point 1 below/ToLeft point 2
    {
        //so for ease we're going to pick point2 at the top right and we can use Top/Right margin as our origin instead of Top/Left
        //however, this appears a bit buggy, i would assume i'd need to do -section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Right minus relative (opposite of TopLeft on the X/horizontal)
        //but it appears this wasn't accounted for on the right margin? or i'm not entirely understanding the floating/anchor functionality
        horizontal = new HorizontalPosition(-(templateItem.X2 * widthMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.RightMargin);
        vertical = new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + (templateItem.Y2 * heightMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin);
        requiresNegativeTransform = true;
    }
    else if (templateItem.X > templateItem.X2 && templateItem.Y < templateItem.Y2)//negative pitch, point 1 above/ToRight point 2
    {
        //opposite of previous in that we're going to pick point1 but everything else will be the same
        horizontal = new HorizontalPosition(-(templateItem.X * widthMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, HorizontalPositionAnchor.RightMargin);
        vertical = new VerticalPosition(section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Top + (templateItem.Y * heightMultiplier), LengthUnit.Point, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopMargin);
        requiresNegativeTransform = true;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    var gemboxLineShape = new Shape(document, ShapeType.Line, GemBox.Document.Layout.Floating(horizontal, vertical, size));

    gemboxLineShape.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(new GemBox.Document.Color(templateItem.Pen.Color.R, templateItem.Pen.Color.G, templateItem.Pen.Color.B));
    gemboxLineShape.Outline.Width = templateItem.Pen.Width;

    //this appears to solve my problem.... however, similar to right margin appears to be
    //a bit buggy... at least in the sense that FlipVertical and FlipHorizontal should do different transformations but it doesn't
    gemboxLineShape.Layout.Transform.FlipVertical = requiresNegativeTransform;

    return gemboxLineShape;
}
```